# ReferenceError: Cannot access <imported const> before initialization in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using react when importing redux action types constants, there is **"ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST' before initialization"**

**reducers**

```
import { AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST, AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS, AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE } from "../actions";

function auth(state = { authorized: false }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, inProcess: true, failed: false };
        case AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, user: action.user, authorized: true, failed: false, inProcess: false };
        case AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, inProcess: false, failed: true, authorized: false }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default auth;
```

**actions**

```
import request from 'common/request';

const AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST = "AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST";
const AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE = "AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE";
const AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS = "AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS";

export { AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST, AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS };

...
```

Comment: Perhaps you have some circular dependency somewhere. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Can you say on which line the error is thrown? I don't see the reason in the posed code.

Comment: `case AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST:`